# Pre-populate values of custom and built-in attributes on Azure B2C Signup Page

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have an Azure AD B2C Signup page and I have custom attributes when signing up. I want these attributes to be pre-populated with user related data and make some of them readonly. I know that I need to use a custom policy for this but dont know how to start. Does anyone have any sample on this? or a link that explains how to?

Answer (score 0):

**2022 December:** Still we need to configure custom policies and upload them into Azure. Steps are as follows:

1. Create a certificate and use that thumbprint when signing the token.
2. Upload that same certificate to Identity Experience Framework > Policy Keys
3. Organize custom policies using [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom)
4. Use the sample code to generate the SignUp [link](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/invite)